# Metodo constructor en PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase y aún estoy un poco verde. Tengo que hacer esto:

***Crea un método constructor para el tipo de objetos "Profesor", en el que se indiquen como parámetros el código, nombre, primer apellido, segundo apellido y especialidad. Este método debe asignar al atributo "apellidos" los datos de primer apellido y segundo apellido que se han pasado como parámetros, uniéndolos con un espacio entre ellos***

He creado el objeto Profesor que es un objeto heredado de otro

```
CREATE TYPE Profesor UNDER MiembroEscolar(

especialidad VARCHAR2(20),
antiguedad INTEGER

);
```

He creado esta funcion para hacer lo que mandan, pero no estoy seguro del todo, de tenerlo bien:

```
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor(nombre VARCHAR2, primerApellido VARCHAR2,segundoApellido VARCHAR2, especialidad VARCHAR2)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Profesor AS 
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor (nombre VARCHAR2, primerApellido VARCHAR2,segundoApellido VARCHAR2, especialidad VARCHAR2)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT
IS 
DECLARE apellidos;
BEGIN
SET apellidos = self.primerApellido + ' ' + self.segundoApellido;

RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Funciona? lo hace bien? lo probaste? cual es la duda?

Comment: Mi duda es si está bien construido, estoy un poco verde en este sentido y necesito un poco de lucidez.

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar.. lo probaste?